# Express the distance two points and optimize the area of a triangle.

Tags: derivatives, optimization, area

Consider the parabola $\mathcal{P}$ of equation $\;y = x^2,$ and the line $L$ of equation $y = x+6.$ Let $P(x_P,y_P)$ be a point on the arc of the parabola $\mathcal{P}$ below $L.$ Let $A$ and $B$ be the points of intersection of $\mathcal{P}$ and $L.$

a) Find an equation of the line $L_P$ passing through $P$ which is perpendicular to $L.$

b) Let $Q_P$ be the point of intersection of $L$ and $L_P.$ Express the distance between $P$ and $Q_P$ using only $x_P$ and $y_P.$

c) Find the point $P$ on the arc of $\mathcal{P}$ below $L$ such that the area of the triangle $APB$ is maximal.

I had no problem doing part a) and got $y=8-x,$ however, I cannot continue further with part b) and c) [image]without hesitation. Please help me!

Comment: There are many points on the parabola, bellow L. From your answer to a) it is clear you have chosen one particular point. That's why your coefficient 8 is fixed and you cannot continue. The point P has to be arbitrary. In the equation of $L_p$ should be a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You can easily find out the coordinates of $Q_P$ by solving the system of linear equations
\begin{align}
y-x=6\\
x+y=8
\end{align}
Knowing  $Q_P$ you can express the distance between  $P$ and $Q_P$ in terms of  $(x_P,y_P)$.

For the third part, first find out the distance between $A$ and $B$. Let that distance be  $b$. Let the distance between  $P$ and $Q_P$ be $h$. Then the area of triangle is $\frac{bh}{2}$. Note that the only variables are  $x_P$ and $y_P$. Now use the relation $y=x^2$ and take the derivative of area with respect to either $x$ or $y$. (Depends on your substitution.) I hope you know how to proceed.

P.S:My answer is based on the assumption that your first part is correct.